# How can I block certain words in a SharePoint Field in a List I've created

Tags: validation

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do block certain types of words or phrases within a field in my SharePoint list.

My List contains a field labelled **Error Messag**e. I would like this field to be left blank if no error message exists.

I also would like to block certain types of words / sentences from being entered. For example: `N/A`, `No Error Message`, `Please see attachment`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSLink attached to the column to validate data on client side. To do this on server side (farm solution), you can create event receiver for `ItemAdding` and `ItemUpdating` events. If data is wrong, just set `SPItemEventProperties.Status` property to `SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError` in event handler. If farm solution can't be used, you can create remote event receiver in provider hosted add-in.

You should check standard validation formula in field settings too. This would be easier to do and maybe will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

SharePoint Validation settings can help you set up some basic validation on columns OOB. Try reading more on how to write validation formulas. This[Link](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com.au/2015/10/sharepoint-column-validation-examples.html)
will be a good start.